# Parsing with Xpath

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div class='data'>
  <div class='user_name'>Lankesh</div>
  <div class='user_details'>
    <div class='country'>Srilanka</div>
    <div class='age'>9</div>
  </div>
  <div class='user_name'>Bob</div>
  <div class='user_details'>
    <div class='country'>US</div>
    <div class='age'>54</div>
  </div>
  <div class='user_name'>Deiter</div>
  <div class='user_details'>
    <div class='country'>Germany</div>
    <div class='age'>34</div>
  </div>
  <div class='user_name'>Yakob</div>
  <div class='user_details'>
    <div class='country'>Syria</div>
    <div class='age'>90</div>
  </div>
  <div class='user_name'>Qureshi</div>
  <div class='user_details'>
    <div class='country'>Afgan</div>
    <div class='age'>56</div>
  </div>
  <div class='user_name'>Smith George</div>
  <div class='user_details'>
    <div class='country'>India</div>
    <div class='age'>23</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the following Ruby code:

```
require 'nokogiri'

sample_html = File.open("r.htm", "r").read

n = Nokogiri::HTML::parse sample_html

xpaths = {}

xpaths[:name] = "//div[@class = 'user_name']/text()"
xpaths[:country] = "//div[@class = 'country']/text()"
xpaths[:age] = "//div[@class = 'age']/text()"

full_path = xpaths.values.join(" | ")

n.xpath(full_path).each do |i|
  puts i
end
```

This works to extract data, but how can I chunk (name, age and country) so that I can extract the parsed data into a structure more easily.

- Since name is outside the user_details block, I am unable to write a query like: `//div[@class = 'user_details']` and extract each attribute.
- I know I can chunk the array into groups of 3; but I am looking for xpath based solution, because my actual need has varying number of child properties.
- Silly, but: anyway to somehow inject characters to the extracted text, during parsing?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me start out by saying it would be better to adjust the HTML to wrap each user block in its own containing div:

```
<div class='user'>
    <div class='name'>John</div>
    <div class='details'>
        <div class='country'>US</div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you could simply query each user block separately using `"//div[@class = 'user']"`. You are probably not in control of the HTML, though.

Given the current situation I would propose to simply obtain the `user_name` divs, as well as the `user_details` divs and zip them together. Then, you can create a Hash from the user details based on the child divs (`.xpath("div")`) which will work for any amount of user_details and uses their class attribute as a Hash key and their text as a value. Note this implementation only works on single-level user_details. Of course this will have to be adjusted if not all user_details child divs will have a class attribute. But judging from your example input they do.

```
require 'pp'
require 'nokogiri'

sample_html = File.open("r.htm", "r").read

n = Nokogiri::HTML::parse sample_html

user_names = n.xpath("//div[@class = 'user_name']")
user_details = n.xpath("//div[@class = 'user_details']")

users = user_names.zip(user_details).map do |name, details|
  {
    name: name.text,
    details: Hash[details.xpath("div").map { |d| [d['class'].to_sym, d.text] }]
  }
end

pp users

# [{:name=>"Lankesh", :details=>{:country=>"Srilanka", :age=>"9"}},
#  {:name=>"Bob", :details=>{:country=>"US", :age=>"54"}},
#  {:name=>"Deiter", :details=>{:country=>"Germany", :age=>"34"}},
#  {:name=>"Yakob", :details=>{:country=>"Syria", :age=>"90"}},
#  {:name=>"Qureshi", :details=>{:country=>"Afgan", :age=>"56"}},
#  {:name=>"Smith George", :details=>{:country=>"India", :age=>"23"}}]
```

Comment: Yes, you have rightly guessed, I don't have control over the HTML. I  understand zipping. But isn't there a way to have this done using XPath (perhaps I am imaging stuff about XPath)

Comment: I do not think so, primarily because XPath returns a flat list of results and since your source is not grouped neither will the results. Is there any reason you want it to be done in XPath only? You said it was because user_details has a varying number of properties, but my solution addresses that while parsing it into a data structure, which is what you want right :)?

Comment: You are right, but somehow was confused by how it actually parses, thats why I was looking further. You answer is certainly right. But, just look for another question I am posting; thats what I really want help with, was trying to understand XPath in this.